# Javascript format currency custom format

Tags: javascript, html, css, currency

I need help with formatting a number.
My output is currency format. So $234.22
But I need to make it, so the 22 visually looks like to the power of 22, and the "." no longer shows.

So Dollars = X;  Cents = Power to.(vissualy).
X^Cents

Could do some weird logic with cutting up the number, formatting Dollars/cents and make them show like that, but was wandering if theres a library or an easier way.

All search gives me square roots/power to,and other math functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to display the result like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div id="first" style="display: inline-block;font-size: 20px;">
        $234
    </div>
    <div id="second" style="display: inline-block;padding-left: 5px;vertical-align: super;">
        22
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP is asking a Javascript solution.

Comment: @connexo the Javascript solution is to get the two values via var result = value.split(".") and then document.getElementById("first").innerText = result[0]; document.getElementById("second").innerText = result[1]; I can add this to the answer if it improves its quality. I avoided it, as it seemed that the answer is more understandable. But if it is not the case, please, let me know, I will add this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

with absolute positioning:

```css
.parent{
  position:relative
}

.value{
  font-size:16px
}

.cent{
  font-size:10px;
  position:absolute;
  padding-left:2px;
  top:-10%
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="value">$200000</span>
  <span class="cent">23</span>
</div>
```

with flexbox:

```css
.parent{
  display:flex;
  align-items:start
}

.cent{
  font-size:10px;
  padding-left:3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="value">$200000</span>
  <span class="cent">23</span>
</div>
```

Javascript solution:

```js
let string = "$234.22"

let array = string.split('.')
const container = document.getElementById('output');
let value = document.createElement('span')
value.textContent = array[0]

let cent = document.createElement('span')
cent.textContent = array[1]
cent.classList.add('cent')

container.appendChild(value)
container.appendChild(cent)
```

```css
#output{
  display:flex;
  align-items:start
}

.cent{
  font-size:10px;
  padding-left:3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: OP is asking a Javascript solution.

Comment: I inserted a js solution